# Django Template Styles and CSS disappear with middleware

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-templates, django-views

I have custom middleware, when I add it to my MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES tuple in my settings.py all of the css and images on the site disappear leaving the site with just text.

**middleware.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import redirect
from django.core import urlresolvers

class AcceptTOSMiddleware(object):
    def process_request(self, request):
        login_url = urlresolvers.reverse('login')
        tos_url = urlresolvers.reverse('tos')
        if request.path not in [login_url, tos_url]:
            profile = request.user.get_profile()
            if not profile.tos:
                return redirect(tos_url)
        return None
```

**settings.py**

```
MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.locale.LocaleMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.flatpages.middleware.FlatpageFallbackMiddleware',
    'pagination.middleware.PaginationMiddleware',
    'utils.middleware.AcceptTOSMiddleware'
)
```

Does anyone know why this would happen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. This should **only happen in development**, otherwise the HTTPD would serve the static files and there would be nothing on django's side to block it,
2. Read runserver's **console output**, it should show that requests for static files are responded with a 3xx redirect (probably 301),
3. For development, your middleware should **also check** if `request.path` doesn't start with `settings.STATIC_URL` nor `settings.MEDIA_URL`, and `return None` in that case.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you're serving static files through Django; perhaps you're using the development server?

As written, your middleware will redirect for any path that isn't login-related, including images and CSS. You might also exclude everything under STATIC_URL and MEDIA_URL.